# To judge identical objects, bool function gives two different results in python

Tags: python, types, boolean

I need to create a list consisting of 10 different Python objects that are falsy. The list must have the property that `a is b` evaluates to `False` whenever `a` and `b` are entries of the list in different positions. I find one, but two entries confuses me: `0<0` and `False`.
I write some codes to test whether the two objects are identical.

```py
 bool(0>0 is False)
```

The result is `False`.

But when I run the code:

```py
mylist=[0>0,False]
bool(mylist[0] is mylist[1])
```

it returns `True`.

So are the two objects identical or not in Python?

Comment: ```print(bool((0>0)== False))```, I think that it is evaluating the first expression. This will give what you want

Comment: Your first expression is not what you think it is due to operator precedence in python.

Comment: If you print out mylist you will see you answer. mylist returns [False, False] because it evaluates the expressions first then perform the "is" operator.

Comment: @VRComp: I don't think the OP is questioning that the individual items are falsy.

Comment: @quamrana you are correct. I was just providing a reason why this might be happening due to operator precedence as you pointed out above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line is considered as

```
0 > (0 is False)
```

Put it this way and it will work:

```
(0 > 0) is False   # ==> True
```

Comment: This is not correct explanation of the evaluation order. There is chaining feature involved.

Comment: Right buran, I short-circuited one too much

Comment: This explanation is plain wrong. See @buran's answer for the right explanation.

Answer (score 3):

[Looking at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), look at the note:

> Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, **all have
> the same precedence and have a left-to-right chaining feature** as
> described in the [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) section.

Bold is mine.

Basically, your expression `0>0 is False` is equivalent to
`(0>0) and (0 is False)`, which is `False and False`, so `bool(False)` -> `False`.

As mentioned in other answers, adding brackets will solve the problem `(0 > 0) is False`

Comment: This is the correct explanation and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parentheses...

```
bool(0>0 is False)
```

is `False` because <s>the steps are to first calculate `0 is False` and then checking whether `0 > (0 is False)`.</s> python "chains" logical clauses.
Consider for instance a more familiar case of chaining:

```
4 > 2 > 9
```

which is equivalent to

```
(4 > 2) and (2 > 9)  # => True and False => False
```

So the chaining happening in your case is equivalent to

```
(0 > 0) and (0 is False)  # => False and False (+ syntax-warning) => False
```

which is, of course, `False`.

If you try the following though -

```
bool((0 > 0) is False)
```

You get the required `True`

---

Edited to actually be correct thanks to comments and based on @buran's answer.
Thanks for the correction and sorry for the original answer being misleading.

Comment: The explanation is wrong. `>` and `is` have the same precedence, as stated in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence, so chaining takes place. See @buran's answer for a correct explanation.

Comment: You're right. Thanks! Corrected and referred.